# Simple bash script loop 2 variables

Tags: bash

while it may seem simple i can't figure this and and i don't wanna complicate it with python.
I'm trying to get 2 variables from a "cat file.txt" in a loop.
For just one variable it's simple:

```
   for i in `cat mylist`; do
     echo ${i}
done
```

In this example we have just one word per line.

I need to make 2 separate variables from a line that contains 2 words/numbers per line separated by tab or space.

```
root@hostname#cat iplist 
192.168.0.1 device1

192.168.0.2 device2

192.168.3.2 device3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a while loop, and let read split the variables:

```
while read -r a b; do
   # do stuff with "$a" and "$b"
done < file
```

Comment: what does -r flag do ?

Comment: It prevents the backslashes to be parsed, so if you have a value with `\t`, with `-r` it will remain like this in the variable, without `-r` it will be converted to a tab.

Comment: Can't adapt it to my needs(meaning i can't figure it out) , i already saw this syntax used around.

Comment: managed to do it finally , the file after done was confusing me , like why after done? . :)

Comment: @blackbrayn Because the file becomes input for the entire loop

Comment: @user000001:  without the `-r` the characters `\t` get converted to `t`, not a tab (try it).  Same with others like four characters `\r\n` get converted to `rn`.

Comment: @cdarke Yup, you are right. The relevant quote from the man page only mentions newlines: `-r   
    If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character.
    The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a backslash-newline
    pair can not be used as a line continuation.` It should be almost always added in my opinion.

Comment: @user000001: agreed, the code you posted is absolutely right.  I have always wondered why `read` does the `\\` stripping by default.  SFAIKT it has always done so (goes back to the 1980s), but I cannot find a source which says why it was done like that.